# How to view my balance method using MVC pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to programming and I've been playing around with asp.net and the MVC pattern in which I got stuck. I'll provide the code snippet bellow.

My People's class inheriting from CurrentAccount

```
public class People:CurrentAccount
{

    // Creating customers
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    private int _age;
    //Setting restriction to account at age 18
    public int age
    {
        get
        {
            return _age;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value>18)
            {
                _age = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Bank's current policies for having an account is over 18");
            }
        }
    }



    CurrentAccount CA;


    public People()
    {
        CA = new CurrentAccount();

    }


}
```

}

```
public class CurrentAccount : IAccount
{


     double balance = 0;

    public void deposit(double money)
    {
        balance +=  money;


    }

    public void withdraw(double money)
    {

        if (balance < 0)
        {
            balance -= money;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Insuffient amount");
        }



    }

   public double Balance()
    {
        return balance;
    }


}
```

And my Controller`

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Deposit()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(double money)
    {
        People p = new People()
       p.deposit(money);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Balance()
    {
        People p = new People();
        p.Balance();
        return View();
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how to pass in the balance method that holds in the value after i deposit and View it.
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do just `p.balance()` in deposit itself? It's the same class anyway.

Comment: From what I can tell this won't work right? You are creating a new People object so any money you deposit will just be lost after one call. NOTE use Pascal case when doing c#!

Comment: Thanks for the commends and feedback.. How would I pass a model in the view for that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,As per my understanding of  your question and  comments above, i hope you want to pass a model to your view and get the properties you want. If so, that is very easy .

Syntax:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    object model
)
```

Controller Code:

```
 public ActionResult Balance()
    {
        People p = new People();
        p.Balance();
        return View(p);  //passing the model object
    }
```

View Code:

@model People

```
<body>
    Your balance is @Model.balance
</body>
```

Note:

I just took the balance as example, you can set any value in the controller and show that value in view

And one more thing, your name of action method and view file name should be same for the above syntax to work,otherwise you can use other syntax as mentioned below.

**official Source:**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.Object%29

Hope this will be helpful for you, kindly let me know thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Thanks! Really useful!

Comment: @Tarek , i hope the above answer was helpful and you got the solution from that, if so ,can you mark it as an answer, so that others will see this answer  when they are stucked to the similar problem. Thanks karthik

Comment: Apologies. Done!